# GWT Eventservice: how to detect client side timeout on server side

Tags: java, events, gwt, timeout, gwt-eventservice

i'm coding on a game project for university at the moment and we are using GWT and GWT EventService.

At the beginning the client enters the main-lobby. A Listener and an UnlistenListener will be registred to the server. The UnlistenerListener registers a UnlistenEvent which contains the username. "User Join" is fired.

On the server-side we have a list of all active users ("joined users"). When a user closes his browser, the UnlistenEvent will be fired 90 seconds after. The other users receive the event, but the question now is: How can i handle this time out on the server side? The event will be fired by the EventService itself and will be received by the other clients but i dont know how to catch this moment and handle it manually on the server side to delist the user from the "active user"-list. An event like "user leave" should be fired by the server as it detects the time out.

The list of active users stays server-side, so all i want is to have a procedure which deletes the "time outed" user in the list of active users.

Can anybody help?

Comment: GWT Events are only for the client side. To notify the server, you would have to make an RPC call with the User object that "timed out". Somewhere in your code, you will have to attach a `UnlistenEventHandler` that makes an RPC call.

Answer (score 0):

We now have frameworks and HTML5 websockets for the server to push information to the client.

I suggest using [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere), or checking [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940822/how-do-i-choose-a-gwt-client-websocket-library) for more choices.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

EventRegistry er = EventRegistryFactory.getInstance().getEventRegistry();

```
public MessagesRpcServiceImpl() {
    super();

    theUserManager = UserManagerFactory.getInstance().getUserManager();
    theUserManager.getUserActivityScheduler().addTimeoutListener(new UserTimeoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeout(UserInfo arg0) {

            List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (Domain d : er.getListenDomains()) {
                ids.add(d.getName());
            }
            ids.remove("GLOBAL");


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I can understand from the library documentation/javadoc it is a bridge between clients and no listening in server side is provided. As a confirm the javadoc refers only to client side code.

Maybe you can modify the library and add a listener to the EventRegistry, it looks a good point where listen the event flow.